# xslt for converting one element to attribute among multiple

Tags: xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0

I have an xml with subelements and need to change one of the subelement to attribute using XSLT 1.0

```
<TransportationRequest>
<actionCode>01</actionCode>
<ContractConditionCode>DC</ContractConditionCode>
<ShippingTypeCode>17</ShippingTypeCode>
<MovementTypeCode>3</MovementTypeCode>
<DangerousGoodsIndicator>false</DangerousGoodsIndicator>
<DefaultCurrencyCode>SAR</DefaultCurrencyCode>
```

The Expected xml is as below using the XSLT code:

```
<TransportationRequest actionCode="01">
  <ContractConditionCode>DC</ContractConditionCode>
  <ShippingTypeCode>17</ShippingTypeCode>
  <MovementTypeCode>3</MovementTypeCode>
  <DangerousGoodsIndicator>false</DangerousGoodsIndicator>
  <DefaultCurrencyCode>SAR</DefaultCurrencyCode>
```

Comment: And what s your question?

Answer (score 0):

First, close the root tag on your xml:

```
<TransportationRequest>
<actionCode>01</actionCode>
<ContractConditionCode>DC</ContractConditionCode>
<ShippingTypeCode>17</ShippingTypeCode>
<MovementTypeCode>3</MovementTypeCode>
<DangerousGoodsIndicator>false</DangerousGoodsIndicator>
<DefaultCurrencyCode>SAR</DefaultCurrencyCode>
</TransportationRequest>
```

then this xsl will do what you asked for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <!-- Copy every node as is -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TransportationRequest">
    <!-- transform the TransportationRequest node in a special way -->
        <xsl:element name="TransportationRequest">
            <xsl:attribute name="actionCode"><xsl:value-of select="actionCode" /></xsl:attribute>
        <!-- don't transform the actionCode node (is in the attribute) -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[name()!='actionCode']"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to it like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="TransportationRequest">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="actionCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="actionCode"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="actionCode"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZYrpW/1